# Nested SQL evaluation question with unnest

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unnest

this may be a basic question but I just couldn't figure it out. Sample data and query could be found [here](https://developers.google.com/ads-data-hub/guides/paths#first-touch). (under the "First-touch" tab)

I'll skip the marketing terminology here but basically what the query does is attributing credits/points to placements (ads) based on certain rule. Here, the rule is "first-touch", which means the credit goes to the first ad user interacted with - could be view or click. The "FLOODLIGHT" here means the user takes action to actually buy the product (conversion).

As you can see in the sample data, user 1 has one conversion and the first ad is placement 22 (first-touch), so 22 gets 1 point. User 2 has two conversions and the first ad of each is 11, so 11 gets 2 points.

The logic is quite simple here but I had a difficult time understanding the query itself. What's the point of comparing `prev_conversion_event.event_time < conversion_event.event_time`? Aren't they essentially the same? I mean both of them came from `UNNEST(t.*_path.events)`. And `attributed_event.event_time` also came from the same place.

What does `prev_conversion_event.event_time`, `conversion_event.event_time`, and `attributed_event.event_time` evaluate to in this scenario anyway? I'm just confused as hell here. Much appreciate the help!

For convenience I'm pasting the sample data, the query and output below:
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQRW7.png)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFkTp.png)

```
/* Substitute *_paths for the specific paths table that you want to query. */
SELECT
  (
  SELECT
    attributed_event_metadata.placement_id
  FROM (
    SELECT
      AS STRUCT attributed_event.placement_id,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY attributed_event.event_time ASC) AS rank
    FROM
      UNNEST(t.*_paths.events) AS attributed_event
    WHERE
      attributed_event.event_type != "FLOODLIGHT"
      AND attributed_event.event_time < conversion_event.event_time
      AND attributed_event.event_time > (
      SELECT
        IFNULL( (
          SELECT
            MAX(prev_conversion_event.event_time) AS event_time
          FROM
            UNNEST(t.*_paths.events) AS prev_conversion_event
          WHERE
            prev_conversion_event.event_type = "FLOODLIGHT"
            AND prev_conversion_event.event_time < conversion_event.event_time),
          0)) ) AS attributed_event_metadata
  WHERE
    attributed_event_metadata.rank = 1) AS placement_id,
  COUNT(*) AS credit
FROM
  adh.*_paths AS t,
  UNNEST(*_paths.events) AS conversion_event
WHERE
  conversion_event.event_type = "FLOODLIGHT"
GROUP BY
  placement_id
HAVING
  placement_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  credit DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a quite convoluted query to be fair, I think I know what are you asking, please correct me if not the case.

> What's the point of comparing prev_conversion_event.event_time < conversion_event.event_time?

You are doing something like "I want all the events from this (unnest), and for every event, I want to know which events are the predecessor of each other".

Say you have [A, B, C, D] and they are ordered in succession (A happened before B, A and B happened before C, and so on), the result of that unnesting and joining over that condition will get you something like `[A:(NULL), B:(A), C:(A, B), D:(A, B, C)]` (excuse the notation, hope it is not confusing), being each key:value pair, the Event:(Predecessors). Note that A has no events before it, but B has A, etc. 
Now you have a nice table with all the conversion events joined with the events that happened before that one.

Comment: Hi @Francesco! Thank you so much for replying! This helps but I'm still not quite sure how the result you mentioned was generated. In sample data, as far as I understand, `prev_conversion_event.event_time` is a list of 7 integers (event_time), so is `conversion_event.event_time`. How does comparing 2 identical lists of integers generate the table you mentioned? I'm definitely wrong somewhere but not sure how to correct myself.

Comment: Well, it doesn't right off the bat. 
UNNESTING will fan-out all the members of the nested element, but then the WHERE conditional will make it so that only the ones meeting the logic (the one I shared) get shown in your final query. 

Try picking this up with a piece of paper, from the inner-most query and outward, by evaluating what each of the sub-queries should look like, and it will be much more clearer. (Or run the sub-queries individually in BigQuery, whatever works for you)